# Cygwin gawk doesn't pipe when called explicitly

Tags: cygwin, awk, pipe

That's the best description I can think of, apologies if it's a little esoteric.

I have cygwin installed on Win 10, Build 16299 but it's installed with the non-administrator option; there is no option to install as admin on this PC.

When executing the following line, it runs when gawk is found using the PATH but not when I explicitly tell it where to find the executable. Any suggestions?

```
gawk "BEGIN { print \"echo Hello mum\" | \"./cygwin/sh\" }"
Hello mum

.\cygwin\gawk "BEGIN { print \"echo Hello mum\" | \"./cygwin/sh\" }"
gawk: cmd. line:1: fatal: can't open pipe `./cygwin/sh' for output (No such file or directory)
```

The cygwin directory is a subset of cygwin commands along with all the dlls copied from \cygwin64\bin\

Answer (score 0):

Suppose You run the command from the directory `/home/user'.

When You run `gawk` then $CWD (current working directory) is set to `/home/user`.

When You run `.\cygwin\gawk` then $CWD is set to `/home/user/cygwin`. In this case `./cygwin/sh` points to `/home/user/cygwin/cygwin`.

Let's try this:

```
.\cygwin\gawk "BEGIN { print \"echo Hello mum\" | \"./sh\" }"
```

Comment: Thank you Tomasz. I did try that but had the same result. I wondered if it was a MSFT OneDrive issue as I am working inside a replicated OneDrive (permissions maybe) but didn't appear to be that.

I looked closer at the contents of my subset of cygwin\bin folder and removed all the .dlls on a whim (there have been many whims) and it now works. Sorry for the wild goose chase but in summary don't copy the dlls when making a subset folder.